# MySQL Left Join with SUM and Where clause returning Null

Tags: mysql

I have a query am having issues with,

```
SELECT id, name, cc, total FROM goods gd 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(*) as cc, status, pid, SUM(number) as total FROM prices)pr 
ON pr.pid = gd.id AND pr.status = 0 WHERE gd.id=20
```

When I run this query on local server if fetches correctly but on my remote server the cc and total is returned null.

Please any idea on the cause?
Note: if I removed count(*) and SUM(number) it returns multiple rows, I want the Left join to get me total matches and sum of number in the second table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT id, name, cc, total
FROM goods gd LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT count(*) as cc, status, pid, SUM(number) as total
      FROM prices
     ) pr 
     ON pr.pid = gd.id AND pr.status = 0
WHERE gd.id=20;
```

The subquery is using a MySQL (mis)feature that allows you to have columns in the `select`, such as `pid` that are not in the `group by` and are not in aggregated columns.  MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) is quite explicit that the values for such columns come from arbitrary matching records and this feature should only be used when all the values for the column are the same in a group.

What is happening is that the arbitrary column on your server does *not* have the value of 20.  By coincidence, on your local server, it does.

You also have a problem with `status`, so that logic should not be stable either.

Do you want the sum where `status = 0`, like this?

```
SELECT gd.id, gd.name, pr.cc, pr.total
FROM goods gd LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT count(*) as cc, status, pid, SUM(number) as total
      FROM prices
      WHERE status = 0
      GROUP BY pid
     ) pr 
     ON pr.pid = gd.id
WHERE gd.id = 20;
```

Or, do you want to match only records where `status` is always equal to `0`?

```
SELECT gd.id, gd.name, pr.cc, pr.total
FROM goods gd LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT count(*) as cc, status, pid, SUM(number) as total
      FROM prices
      GROUP BY pid
      HAVING min(status) = 0 and max(status) = 0
     ) pr 
     ON pr.pid = gd.id
WHERE gd.id = 20;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon-Linoff for the comprehensive answer, would have choose your answer but that of echo_Me came in first. Thanks again.

Comment: @andychukse . . . Authors have the right to choose whatever answer they think is best.  Your question was:  "Please any idea on the cause?", it was not "how can I fix this".  Also, echo_me's answer does not handle the issue with `status`, which you will find is a lingering problem.

Comment: I just noticed the status issue you pointed out, I will be updating your answer as the better on. Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `group by pid` in joined query.

```
SELECT id, name, cc, total FROM goods gd 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(*) as cc, status, pid, SUM(number) as total 
           FROM prices group by pid)pr 
ON pr.pid = gd.id AND pr.status = 0 
WHERE gd.id=20
```

Comment: Sorry, I still had issues with Sum(number) only where status=0 @Glordon-Linoff answer below fixes that. Thanks

Comment: you can pass `pr.status = 0` in the where clause instead of beeing in ON clause.